# UITabController with shared title bar for all tab view items

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

When my app launches, I'll have an initial list that the user chooses from. Once chosen, the user should be taken to a UITabController that has content related to the item chosen on the initial list.

For the user to get back to that list, I'd like to have a Title/Tool bar at the top of the app. The bar should contain a title and a button that let's the user get back to that first modal list of items where a new item can be chosen.

I know I can have each individual view controller specify a title as well as a button, but I'd like it controlled at the AppDelegate rather than at each view so that each view doesn't have to contain duplicate logic to accomplish this.

Ideally my app would be a UINavigationController with a UIViewController that contains a UITabViewController; however, it seems that Apple frowns on this type of flow.

Is there a way to manage this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to do this at the tab bar controller level. You could make a subclass of UIViewController to add some methods and properties to take care of your title bar, and then have each of your individual controllers inherit from that class instead of directly from UIViewController